# Mirroring input content with non-printable chars like CTRL, ALT or shift key

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, non-printing-characters

When non-printable char is pressed, it's replaced with let's say for CTRL=17 with **"[CTRL]"**.
Here is code an example

```
$('#textbox1').keyup(function (event) {
    if (8 != event.keyCode) {
       if(17==event.keyCode){
        $('#textbox1').val($('#textbox1').val()+"[CTRL]")
        $('#textbox2').val($('#textbox1').val());
       }else{
        $('#textbox2').val($('#textbox1').val());
       }

    } else {

        $('#textbox2').val($('#textbox1').val());
    }
});
```

the problem is when user presses backspace the second input must reflect the content of the first one, so **"[CTRL]"** must be deleted at once like any other chars.

Comment: don't you read the title ?                                    non-printable chars are not supported with .val()

Comment: Is this linear, meaning if the user presses backspace if deletes the last inputted character, or can they click around to different parts of the text box and delete characters at any place?

Comment: @Gavin The point is capturing non-printable chars and handle them like other printable chars specially when backspace

Comment: You need to keep a list containing the pressed key codes, otherwise it's impossible to decide whether "[Ctrl]" stands there because the user pressed Ctrl or because he typed it letter by letter.

Comment: @elsadek, so what you mean is if your first text box contains "abcdefghijk" and the 2nd text box contains "abc[CTRL]defg[ALT]hijk" then the user can click in between "c" and "d" in the first text box and if they press backspace and it will remove [CTRL]? Or can they only "undo" the last character they entered when they press backspace?

Comment: @Gavin the first case wouldn't be handy for the end user but the second is the closest one to my use case

Comment: Ok, and is it just one-level of undo, or can you undo as far back as the user has started typing?

Comment: @Gavin user may undo many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of the `keyCode` and/or in combination with `charCode` (if required). Basic idea would be:

1. Create a map of all required key codes in an array/object
2. Handle event for say `keydown` and listen for keycode
3. Look for the keycode in your map and if found show it
4. prevent the default (to prevent e.g. say backspace browsing back)
5. If not found in map, let the character go thru as usual.

A very basic example:

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/L7nhZ/***

*Relevant js*:

```
keyMap = {8:"[Backspace]",9:"[Tab]",13:"[Enter]",16:"[Shift]",17:"[Ctrl]",18:"[Alt]",19:"[Break]",20:"[Caps Lock]",27:"[Esc]",32:"[Space]",33:"[Page Up]",34:"[Page Down]",35:"[End]",36:"[Home]",37:"[Left]",38:"[Up]",39:"[Right]",40:"[Down]",45:"[Insert]",46:"[Delete]"};

$("#txt").on("keydown", function(e) {

    // check if the keycode is in the map that what you want
    if (typeof(keyMap[e.keyCode]) !== 'undefined') {

        // if found add the corresponding description to the existing text 
        this.value += keyMap[e.keyCode];

        // prevent the default behavior
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    // if not found, let the entered character go thru as is
});
```

### Edit: (as per the comments)

The concept remains the same, just copying the value to the second input:

***Demo 2: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/L7nhZ/3/***

```
$("#txt1").on("keyup", function(e) {
    if (typeof(keyMap[e.keyCode]) !== 'undefined') {
        this.value += keyMap[e.keyCode];
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    $("#txt2").val(this.value); // copy the value to the second input
});
```

Regarding deletion of the description, I could not get it done by caching the last inserted descrition from the map. Somehow, I kept struggling with the regex with a variable. Anyway, a simpler solution is to just add another event handler for keyup with hard-coded map.

Thanks to @serakfalcon for [(that simple solution)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23502392/javascript-mirroring-input-content-with-non-printable-chars-like-ctrl-alt-or-s#comment37044817_24030736), which we are using here:

```
$('#txt1').keydown(function(event) {
    if(8 == event.keyCode) {
        var el = $(this);
        el.val(el.val().replace(/\[(Tab|Enter|Shift|Ctrl|Alt|Break|Caps Lock|Esc|Space|Page (Up|Down)|End|Home|Left|Up|Right|Down|Insert|Delete)\]$/,' '));
        $("#txt2").val(el.val());
    }
});
```

Comment: that's not what the OP is asking. they want to be able to delete `[CTRL]` in one go when they hit backspace.

Comment: @abhitalks you are missing the important part of the question which is reflecting input value

Comment: @elsadek: yes of course, i am working on that part right now. please give me a few minutes..

Comment: @abhitalks [fify](http://jsfiddle.net/L7nhZ/1/) (unless you want to separate manual entries of `[CTRL]` from ctrl keypresses)

Comment: Thanks a lot @serakfalcon, i was trying to with a cache variable.

Comment: Thanks @abhitalks, if I could make @@serakfalcon share the bounty with you, is it possible ?

Comment: elsadek: Don't worry about the bounty :) You could just award it to @serakfalcon . After all it was he who helped complete the puzzle, and deserves it. In fact I had started answering before you put a bounty, got to know only after posting the answer. More important is the fact that you were able to solve your problem. Cheers!

Comment: This still has the problem that a manually typed [Ctrl] will be treated as if the user pressed Ctrl. It might be worth trading this bug off to avoid a lot more complexity, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can check in the `keydown` for the last character in the input field. If it's a `]` you can remove everything from the right to the last found opening bracket `[`. Unfortunatly this does not work if you're cursor is inside `'[ ]'`.

```
$('#textbox1').keydown(function(event) {
    if(8 == event.keyCode) {
        var element = $(this),
            value = element.val(),
            lastChar = value.slice(-1);

        if(lastChar == ']') {
            var lastIndex = value.lastIndexOf('['),
                index = value.length - lastIndex;

            element.val(value.slice(0, -index) + "]");
        }
    }
});
```

### Fiddle

Comment: This fails if you manually type "[Ctrl]" letter by letter, though.

Comment: also fails when copy/past "[CTRL]" in fisrt input

Answer (score 1):

you can always use a regex.

```
$('#textbox1').keydown(function(event) {
    if(8 == event.keyCode) {
        var el = $(this);
        el.val(el.val().replace(/\[(CTRL|ALT|SHIFT)\]$/,' '));
    }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8nepA/1/)

Edit: [combined with abhitalks code](http://jsfiddle.net/L7nhZ/1/)